# Ordering complex numbers - When is it right and when is it not?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I know there are a lot of questions related to this topic. But, I have one specific doubt. If we order complex numbers, does that mean that we are wrong all the time?
If we say $4 + 3i < 5 + 7i$. I am wrong as I will get $-1 > \frac{1}{16}$ eventually which is incorrect.

How about $3i>2i$. Is that correct? I will get $3>2$ which is correct. 
 My main question is when is the ordering correct and when is that incorrect?

Comment: What do you want $z > w$ to *MEAN*?

Comment: Why do you say $-1 > \frac 1{16}$ is "wrong"?  There are orders that you can make up where $-1 > \frac 1{16}$ is "right".  The question is what do you want your order to *mean*?

Comment: @fleablood I’d love to see a reference to principle roots in an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it as anything you darned well please.

What do you want $z > w$ to *mean*?

You can have it mean $|z| > |w|$ but then you will won't be able to compare $2+3i$ to $3 + 2i$.

You can have it mean if $z = a+bi$ and $w =c+di$ that $z > w$ means $a > c$ or if $a=c$ then $b > d$.  Then you can compare any two numbers but you don't have $z > 0; w > 0$ then $z*w > 0$ or that $z^2 \ge 0$.  SO no algebra or arithmetic will work.

The first $z > w$ means $|z| > |w|$ can give us arithmetic and algebra the the order isn't *total*.  ANd we can't say that that $z < w$ or $z > w$ of $z = w$.  It's very possible byt $z \not < w$ and $z \not > w$ and $z \ne w$.  (Example: $2+3i \ne 3+2i$ and $2 + 3i \not < 3+2i$ and $2+3i \not > 3+2i$.

But *NOTHING* you do will give you an order where:

i) every $a,b$ exactly one and only one of the following is true:  $a < b$ or $b < a$ or $a =b$.

ii)  $a<b$ and $b < c$ will mean $a < c$.

iii) If $a < b$ then $a + c < b+c$ always

iv) if $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.

It is impossible to come up with an order on $\mathbb C$ where all those are true.

(because iii) tells us that $x > 0 \iff -x < 0$ and iii) and iv) tells us that $x^2 \ge 0$ always, but with complex numbers we have $i^2 = -1\ge 0$ and $1^2 = 1 \ge 0$.)

But if those aren't all true you can make up what you want.  There is no "right" or "wrong" way because none of them make a complete ordered field and if you don't have a complete ordered field, no-one *cares* what you do.

You can say $3i > 2i$ if you want.  What do you do about $-3i$ and $2i$ or about $3 + 2i$ and $2 + 3i$?  You can do what you want but you will never have $x^2 \ge 0$ always.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the definition of `<`, `>` and others. Consider representation of complex number $a+bi$ as a pair $(a, b)$ in cartesian coordinate system. Then the question would be about ordering points in two-dimensional space.

Comment: Indeed. One sensible interpretive definition of <,=,> is comparing the [non-de-]signed distance. Every number assigned to the Complex plane consists of the product of two pieces: a sign, consisting of two added parts (counting the sign of $0$ as $+$ instead of $-$ or $\text{zero}$ intermediately, since the default non-signed direction of distance is taken to be positive; i.e. letting sgn$(0):=1$), equaling its direction; and a magnitude, one-part scalar.  Similarly, a number assigned to the Real line consists as well of the product of 2 pieces: a one-dimensional discrete sign; and a magnitude.

Comment: Going with "signed distance" route, the task becomes to decide how properly to normalize (or calculate in the first place) the sign of a multidimensional value to conform to that of one piece (like with the strictly-reals, $−1$
or $+1$). One option is to use the [csgn(z) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Complex_signum), although that hinges on [an artificial] weight preference to Real over other (Imaginary) portion of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering on Complex Numbers isn't really defined because there is no natural definition.

You can define it any way you want. For example, you could define a+ib>c+id if a+b>c+d.

You can define a+ib>c+id to be true when $a^2+b^2>c^2+d^2$. Notice that under this definition -2=2. This doesn't mean that we did anything wrong. We have only changed the meaning of the > sign. Similarly, $-1>\frac{1}{16}$ is also true under this definition.

Comment: " Notice that under this definition -2=2. "  Only if you assume $z > w; z < w$ or $z = w$ are the only three options.  I'd argue that $-2 = 2$ is never true so any order that says it is as "wrong" but $-2\equiv 2$ is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @fleablood i was kinda thinking that changing the meaning of < would also change the value meaning =. But yeah, that's assuming that <,>,= are the only options.

Comment: Well, you are allowed to create systems where  criteria to determine what is required for things to be "equal" change.